# Vue warn - Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '[object Array]'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Well,

I'm trying to do a project of an a Shopping cart with vue.js, and the browser Console is showing this error:

> vue.common.js:576 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '[object Array]' in products"

```
// App.vue

<template>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="products">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <product v-for="product in products" :key="product"></product>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shopping-cart">
        <shopping-cart></shopping-cart>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import ShoppingCart from './components/ShoppingCart.vue'
import Product from './components/Product.vue'

export default {
  created () {
    // dados mockados
    var dummy = [
      {id: 1, title: 'Name of Product 1', price: 40, image: 'product.png'},
      {id: 2, title: 'Name of Product 2', price: 90, image: 'product.png'},
      {id: 3, title: 'Name of Product 3', price: 10, image: 'product.png'},
      {id: 4, title: 'Name of Product 4', price: 20, image: 'product.png'}
    ];

    this.$set('products', dummy)
  },
  data () {
    return {
      products: []
    }
  },
  components: { Product, ShoppingCart }
}

</script>
```

What can I do?

I tried a lot of things and still without success =(

Comment: Push into the product array instead of $set, `this.products.push({id: 1, title: 'Name of Product 1', price: 40, image: 'product.png'}, { the others })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you component name in template is "product" and also the key in for loop is also "product". Either you change Component name to suitable name like.

And you must have forgot to give a name(assign a name of component for tepmplate) to component which you imported. You cannot use imported component just like that without giving it reference name to use it in template.

```
components: { Product:productName, ShoppingCart: shoppingCart }
```

This way you use `<product-name> </product-name>` in template and so after that in for loop, the `product in prodcuts` will work.

Also products array should not work with this way. It should be in computed hook.

```
computed ={}
```

Or I should suggest you should directly asssign it in `data()`

Answer (score 1):

for better working , in the $set method in VUE

the first arg for pass 'this' keyword

some thing like this

```
this.$set(this,'your_object', value)
```

and notice second arg must be String

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with $set method, you need to specify the object as 1st parameter, see full doc [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

so you need to do something like this:`this.$set(this.products, dummy)`
also this will not give you 4 products in the v-for loop. I would suggest to assign the products directly in data()

Comment: I used this: this.$set(this.products, 'products', dummy) and worked for only one product as you said. How can I make the the v-for loop works???
Thanks for the support!

Comment: The best way is to directly assign the array in the data() function, without the dummy var. Other way is to use Object.assign like: `Object.assign(this.products, dummy)`

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
this.products = dummy
```

instead of

```
this.$set('products', dummy)
```

and if you create your array in mounted () better than created () in your single app